# Ok to use numbers as glue and delimiters?

Tags: php, join, types, explode, implode

The PHP docs for `join()` and `explode()` say that the `$glue` and `$delimiter` must be strings. I tried this and it doesn't throw any errors:

```
$glue = -8.5;
$delimiter = 0;
echo join( $glue, explode($delimiter, '1_0_1') ); // '1_-8.5_1'
```

So if I'm checking a `$var` that could be used as `$glue` or `$delimiter`, then is it safe to use `is_string($var) || is_numeric($var)`
as a condition OR are there times where that could be `true` but there'd be an error from the `join()` or `explode()`?

Comment: The fact that it does not show errors does not mean you should care to allow it.

Comment: @bazmegakapa But if it doesn't cause an error, then why would it be unsafe?

Comment: We are talking about glues and delimiters... it is perfectly fine to only allow strings for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just do type casting like this:

```
// note join() is just an alias for implode. 
// i like the symmetry of using implode/explode
echo implode((string) $glue, explode((string) $delimiter, '1_0_1'));
```

At any rate, it appears they were being converted anyway.

Still, it would be good to use `is_string()` and `is_numeric()` to avoid a catchable fatal error if, say, an object was passed.

```
if ((is_string($glue) || is_numeric($glue))
    && (is_string($delimiter) || is_numeric($delimiter))
) {
    // objects didn't pass the test, safe to type-cast
    echo implode((string) $glue, explode((string) $delimiter, '1_0_1'));
}
```

---

**Edit**

Per ryanve's suggestion, you could do this too:

```
if (is_scalar($glue) && !is_bool($glue)) { // ...
```

Comment: Thx // Yea I didn't want to use the casting ops because then if an array or object was passed it would try to use 'Array' or 'Object' as the glue/delimiter.

Comment: Also I could almost use `is_scalar()` except that `(string)false` throws an 'Empty delimiter' error and `(string)true` becomes `'1'`.

Comment: @ryanve touche.  perhaps something like `is_scalar($var) && false !== $var` would be the solution.

Comment: `is_scalar($var) && !is_bool($var)` is safer b/c you don't want `true` either b/c it'd use '1' as glue. I just ran a test and it looks like `is_scalar($var) && !is_bool($var)` is slightly faster than `is_string($var) || is_numeric($var)` and I think they are equivalent. See: http://dev.airve.com/demo/speed_tests/php_is_scalar_not_bool.php

Answer (score 1):

PHP performs an implicit cast to string before actually doing the join (which should be `implode` since it sounds cooler). You could even use a class which has the `__toString()` magic function defined too. An integer can always be cast to a string, so there should be no problem, no.

Though, it might be even better to do:

```
try {
    $var = (string)$var;
}
catch(Exception $e) {
    echo "oh, noes, it wasn't castable to a string!";
}
```

To check if it actually is a string. :)

Comment: __toString can not throw an exception. Not one you can catch, anyway ;)

Comment: You are correct. I am too used to converting all recoverable error conditions to exceptions. :)

Comment: Yeah, me too, that's why I ran into it. :)

Answer (score 0):

Manual never says that the $glue and $delimiter "must" be strings.
It just mention the type, an obvious type for the *string* manipulation.
And other types would be just cast to this type - a thing used in PHP everywhere, not a big deal.

Every string operator will cast it's arguments to strings - I don't understand, what makes you wonder here.
say, `TRUE.TRUE` will cast booleans to strings as well.

> it safe to use `is_string($var) || is_numeric($var)`

I see no point in such a checking at all.